# Can I Install Hyperledger Composer deprecated version by cloning it from github?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have cloned the repository from this link
into my PC https://github.com/hyperledger/composer
I need to use composer playground on my pc

Comment: Why do you have to use composer playground ? Hyperledger composer is more than deprecated, it's been end of life for quite a while and the community as well as the people who developed it have moved on

Comment: Thanks for reply,I am working on a project. I needed a decentralized Block chain system. So can I use Fabric  for it

Comment: In that case I would suggest you use the latest version of hyperledger fabric. If you want a good starting development environment you can use the IBM Blockchain Platform VS Code extension as this will provide a nice dev environment for hyperledger fabric

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try that..

Comment: @david_k , IBM Blockchain Platform is by 2022  [withdrawn and replaced with Hyperledger Fabric](https://www.ibm.com/blockchain/platform) ,